# Node / Express / Mocha disable middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I have a hello world app which looks like this:

```
let clientAuthMiddleware = () => (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.client.authorized) {
    return res.status(401).send('Invalid client certificate authentication.');
  }
  return next();
};

function app() {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const https = require('https');
    const express = require('express');

    const app = express();
    app.use(clientAuthMiddleware());

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.socket.getPeerCertificate());
      return res.send('Hello world!');
    });

    https
      .createServer(
        {
          cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/localhost.crt'),
          key: fs.readFileSync('cert/localhost.key'),        
          requestCert: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          ca: fs.readFileSync('cert/ca.crt'),
        },
        app
      )
      .listen(9443);
    
    return app;
}

if (require.main === module) instance = app()
module.exports.app = app
module.exports.authMiddleware = clientAuthMiddleware
```

And a test which looks like:

```
 describe('GET /', function() {
    it('should return Hello world!', function(done) {
          chai.request(app.app()).get('/')
             .end((err, res) => {
                 if (err)done(err);
                 res.should.have.status(200);
                 expect(res.body).to.equal('Hello world!');
                 done();
              });
    });
  });
```

How can I replace authMiddleware in the test, preferably without using some external stubbing library? Isn't there some way I can just rearrange my code so in the test I can just do app.authMiddleware = {my own stub function} ?

Edit: Also, is there a way I can just straightforwardly unit test these endpoints like app.get('/') without making a real HTTP request? I keep searching Google for unit testing Node/Express with Mocha and every resource I find seems to be functional testing making a real request....

Comment: If I understand correct, you are searching for a lib that does what `nock` does. Maybe if it fits your needs I can share an example. I'm saying that because you said: preferably without using some external stubbing library.

Comment: @Danizavtz I'm relatively new to Node, but my understanding is nock is for mocking external HTTP requests, I want to test the endpoints of my own Express app without it actually spinning up a server, listening and making a real request.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in your app using environment variables, if your environment is test or production or development. write condition fro middlware something like this

```
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') { 
        app.use(clientAuthMiddleware()); 
 }
```

And if you want to test your app without making HTTP request, you need to separate the business logic from request handlers.

For example if you have a route "/api/user/login", for the route you have a route hanlder something like

```
 app.post("/api/user/login" , async (req,res) => {
    const response = await login(req.body.email,req.body.password);
    res.status(200).json(response);
 });

 // login function is independent of express 
 // routes and can be easily tested  without api requests
 async function login(email,password) {
    //login logic
 }
```

In this way you can make your business logic independent of express and it can be easily tested without HTTP requests.

Comment: Cheers, so just to be clear; there's no way to test the actual Express route endpoints without making a real HTTP request, i.e. I can't just stitch together a test double request object and call app.get directly?

Comment: Well, i don't think there is a way to test HTTP endpoints without making HTTP requests. On the other side keeping your business logic separate from Framework or Protocol your are using is going to be huge upside. You can swap express with KOA or any other framework or create command line app or using Websockets to do same job or test the units of code without caring about HTTP requests and you don't have to touch any line of code from the business logic, because your business logic is not coupled with the framework you are using, which is how it should be, I hope you get the point.